# Last digit of a large number (Ruby) how to deal with NaN?

Tags: ruby, math

Here's my code:

```
def last_digit(n1, n2)
array = (n1.to_i ** n2.to_i).to_s.split("")
array[-1].to_i
end
```

TEST: The last decimal digit of (2^200)^(2^300), which has over 10^92 decimal digits, is 6

I'm trying to return the last digit of a last number and I'm sure this correct but when I run tests 2 return as failing.

I think it's due to the numbers being too large, how do I get this code to remain accurate no matter how large it gets.

And also how do I deal with NaN, I've searched and struggled to find anything useful.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an effective algorithm which assumes that only the last digit of a number being powered matters. Please, try it out on your tests and feel free to correct any flaw in this implementation that you'll find by running them

```
def digit_of_power(digit, n)
  digit = digit % 10

  case digit
  when 0, 1, 5, 6 then digit
  else
    digit_of_square = digit * digit

    if n.even?
      digit_of_power(digit_of_square, n / 2)
    else
      digit * digit_of_power(digit_of_square, (n - 1) / 2) % 10
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution

```
def last_digit(n1, n2)
  return 1 if n2 == 0
  return 0 if n1 == 0
  exp = (n2 % 4 == 0) ? 4 : n2 % 4
  return (n1**exp) % 10
end
```

You might want to read this article ([finding the last digit of a power](https://brilliant.org/wiki/finding-the-last-digit-of-a-power/)) for a more detailed explanation of the solution to this math problem.

Take a look at the following table:

[image]

You can see that the maximum length for cycle repetition is 4.

For instance:

- 2 * 2 = 4
- 4 * 2 = 8
- 8 * 2 = 16
- 16 * 2 = 32
- 32 * 2 = 64
- 64 * 2 = 128
- 128 * 2 = 256
- 256 * 2 = 512

The last digit in 32 is 2 ( as it is in 512), meaning that after multiplying the digit by 4, it will repeat itself.

The algorithm follows this logic:

You reduce the exponent, knowing that if it is divisible by 4, its new value is 4 because multiplying it 4 times gives you the last digit according to the table above. Otherwise, its value is **n2 % 4**.

As a final step you do this **n1^exp % 10** because you only need the last number.

**Note:**

I tested it successfully with large numbers.

- n1 = 38710248912497124917933333333284108412048102948908149081409204712406
- n2 = 226628148126342643123641923461846128214626

By the way, I realize I am late in responding to your question. I just think it might be helpful for someone else someday.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
ENDINGS = [[0,0,0,0], [1,1,1,1], [2,4,8,6], [3,9,7,1], [4,6,4,6],    
           [5,5,5,5], [6,6,6,6], [7,9,3,1], [8,4,2,6], [9,1,9,1]]

def last_digit_of_power(digit, power)
  return 1 if power.zero?
  ENDINGS[digit][(power-1) % 4]
end
```

**Examples**

Let's try it for `power` equal to `5` and then `6`.

```
(5..6).each do |power|
  puts "\npow = #{power}"
  (0..9).each {|digit| puts "#{digit}: #{last_digit_of_power(digit, power)}"}
end

pow = 5
0: 0
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
4: 4
5: 5
6: 6
7: 7
8: 8
9: 9

pow = 6
0: 0
1: 1
2: 4
3: 9
4: 6
5: 5
6: 6
7: 9
8: 4
9: 1
```

**Explanation**

This uses the same algorithm as employed by @Igor, but I've implemented it differently. It is known (and can be easily demonstrated) that the last digit of each digit `0-9` taken to increasing powers cycles among at most `4` digits. Consider the digit `3`, for example. Since

```
[1,2,3,4,5].map { |power| 3**power } 
  #=> [3, 9, 27, 81, 243]
```

the last digits of `3` taken to each of those `5` powers is `[3, 9, 7, 1, 3]`. Since the last digit of `3**5` is the same as the last digit of `3**1`, we infer than the last digit of `3**6` will be the same as the last digit of `3**(6-4)` (`3**2`), which is `9`, and so on.

Now suppose we wished to calculate the last digit of `3**15`. We see that it will be the same as the last digit of `3**(15-4)` (`3**11`), which in turn will equal the last digit of `3**7` and then the last digit `3**3`, but we already know the last of these, which is `7`. It follows that the last digit of `3**power` is

```
[3, 9, 7, 1][(power-1) % 4]
```

`ENDINGS` provides the last digits for powers `1-4` for each of the digits `0-9`. Note the cycle length is `1` for `0`, `1`, `5` and `6`, is `2` for `4` and `9` and is `4` for `2`, `3`, `7` and `8`. It's most convenient, however, to use a cycle length of `4` for all `10` digits.

`ENDINGS[digit]` equals the four endings of `digit` taken to the powers of `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`. The last digit of the digit `digit` taken to the power `power` therefore equals

```
ENDINGS[digit][(power-1) % 4]
```